# DNSMASQ in Read-Only mode

Tags: raspberrypi, dnsmasq

I have set up my Raspberry Pi 3 to provide an Access Point using the wlan0 interface. However, when I set it to Read-Only mode, DNSMASQ fails to start.

I have tried moving directories such as /etc, /usr, /bin and some more to the RAM memory using tmpfs but it still fails to start. Did anyone manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out what's happening, at least for me. It would try to write to `/var/lib/misc/`, which I had to move into RAM.

You shouldn't need to ever move `/etc`, `/usr` or `/bin` into RAM

**NOTE:** Also make sure you have the `resolvconf` package installed.

Comment: I like to create a read-write `.lib/` directory in `/home` for my Raspberry Pis when they are running read-only, with a bind mount to `/var/lib`. This is mainly because `/var/lib` is meant to be persistent across reboots.